# Delete all "Post Content" from custom post type "Products" through phpmyadmin

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

Using WordPress and WooCommerce, I'm trying to delete all "Post Content" from the "Products" of woocommerce.

The Products reside in a Custom Post Type "Products" and I don't want to delete post content from blog posts, or pages.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with WooCommerce, but the query would be:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET `post_content` = ''
WHERE `post_type` = 'product'
```

Replace `product` with the actual post_type WooCommerce registers products. If you don't know the post_type search for [register_post_type()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) in the plugin files (grep, find in path, ...). If you don't know how to do that, then run the following query:

```
SELECT `post_type`
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` NOT IN ('post','page','attachment','revision','nav_menu_item')
```

You will get a list of all custom registered post types.